# is it normal with android emulator?

Tags: android, process, emulation

hello i was setting up environment for android and when ever i try to launch the android emulator i get this

Before launching emulator screenshot(WITH FIREFOX IN THE BACKGROUND)
[image]

After launching emulator screenshot(WITHOUT FIREFOX) 
[image]

when i freshly start my system PF usage is exactly 290MB after launching Android Emulator it gets to nearly 850MB and as soon as i open Eclipse it nearly gets to 1.01GB

i have Intel Pentium D with 1GB of RAM(as you can see in task manager) and i have only installed SDK 2.3.3 API 10,revision 1 package.

So, is it normal?? cause all things get very slow and response of emulator is very very slow

Comment: The Android emulator is slow as molasses. Invest in a real device, or in a real CPU.

Answer (score 1):

I would say this is normal.  On my netbook (Intel atom N280 w\ 2 gig RAM), the emulator is sluggish.  Running an emulator requires a lot of resources!

If you are serious about Android development, your best bet is getting a real device you can test with.  For most things, its worlds better than using the emulator.  If you have an Android Market account, you can buy a dev phone, but that is pretty expensive.  I am sure there are some cheap Android phones floating around on ebay which would serve you well.

Comment: true but emulator can mimic quite well real devices.. if your budget is not that big or you wanna a test drive of android go for the emulator

Comment: Agreed that the emulator is good for getting your feet wet.  Even if you have a real device, the emulator can be useful at times.  However if you want to undertake a real application, you are either an Android enthusiast or are developing it professionally.  In the former case I would think you would want a phone anyways, and in the latter case its a totally reasonable business expense which will reduce development time and improve the final product.

Answer (score 0):

I can't really tell you how normal is that nevertheless remember that the emulator mimic all a Android Mobile Enviroment this includes quite a lot work to do, i wouldn't think for a moment that the emulator is lightmemory weight, since is based on QEMU

> The Android emulator is a QEMU-based
>   application that provides a virtual
>   ARM mobile device on which you can run
>   your Android applications. It runs a
>   full Android system stack, down to the
>   kernel level, that includes a set of
>   preinstalled applications (such as the
>   dialer) that you can access from your
>   applications. You can choose what
>   version of the Android system you want
>   to run in the emulator by configuring
>   AVDs, and you can also customize the
>   mobile device skin and key mappings.
>   When launching the emulator and at
>   runtime, you can use a variety of
>   commands and options to control the
>   its behaviors.

you migh also want to checkout [this thread](http://groups.google.com/group/android-beginners/browse_thread/thread/0a79c55ce2868841/a366b8da099c55a4?pli=1) there you can get a user insight of the emulator slowness.

Comment: well the symbian emulator is much better.People developing android must look into this

Comment: haven't tried symbian didn't micro$oft gave a big hit to symbia with Nokia alliance?